# c++ class global variable does not name a type in other class

Tags: global-variables

I am tryng to use a global class from my main in another class and it is not working out...

```
PilhaJogo p[7];  //these are my global classes
PilhaSaida s[4];
Card v[60];
PilhaDescarte d;
PilhaEstoque e;
```

This is the function from PilhaDescarte I am trying to use.

```
void Discard(){
setTopo(getTopo()+1);
v[getTopo()].aberta=true;
}
```

This is the header of the class I am trying to use Discard on:

```
#include<Card.h>
#include<PilhaDescarte.h>
#include<PilhaJogo.h>
#include<PilhaSaida.h>
#include<Global.h>

using namespace std;

class PilhaJogo;
class PilhaDescarte;
class PilhaSaida;
class PilhaEstoque
```

### And here is where the error occurs... :

```
void Compra(){
    v[getTopo()+1];
    d.Discard();
}
```

I don't know how to use global variable that are classes in other classes.
And I did initialize all the classes in the main:

```
for(i=0;i<60;i++){
    v[i].nome="0";
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    s[i].setStatus(false);
}

for(i=0;i<7;i++){
    p[i].Inicia(0+4*i,i);
}
d.setBase(0);
d.setTopo(0);
d.Inicia();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand yet, but try to get a look at good manners for C++ programming, because there are some changes you need to do. At first you need to initialize the variables at the constructor and try to get a look about encapsulation, we can't set variables to public. =)

If you want, there is this awesome book (brazilian portuguese):
http://www.cesarkallas.net/arquivos/apostilas/programacao/c_c%2B%2B/ApostilaProgramacaoCppv045.pdf

I am brazilian, I think you are too because of the variables names.